# Spring security giving error 403 after DaoAuthenticationProvider id configured

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

SOLVED - The problem was with the user role, spring expected **ROLE_USER** and I was passing **USER**. Thanks for the tips.

I was trying to secure my Spring Boot application. All works ok with in memory authentication:

```
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("new")
            .password("asd")
            .roles("USER");
```

But I need database authentication, so in my User class I implemented **UserDetails**:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8281468636068319152L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String login;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    private Role role;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(long id, String login, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

        if (role == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (role.equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
            authorities.add(Role.ADMIN);
        }

        authorities.add(Role.USER);

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Role:

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ADMIN,
    USER;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

and created a a service like this to load the user:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
        if ( user == null ) 
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        return user;
    }
}
```

When configuring the application I changed the in memory authentication for this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

The HttpSecurity is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

After this configuration I can't get the applications content because spring thrown error 403: forbidden access

On the console I get:

> 2015-04-01 20:59:51.515 DEBUG 5476 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
>   2015-04-01 20:59:51.516 DEBUG 5476 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
>   2015-04-01 20:59:51.517 DEBUG 5476 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
>   2015-04-01 20:59:51.517 DEBUG 5476 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1

Looks like Spring not find my @RequestMapping after the security configuration.

Any sugestion?

Comment: Please share the code that constructs the `User` object that is returned from `findByLogin()` method.

Comment: As the above comments says the problem might be with how the user is constructed. Can you enable Spring logs (add logging.level.org.springframework: DEBUG into application.properties) and check.